# How to configure cakephp to run in localhost

Tags: cakephp

I have a working cakephp website on the server. I've downloaded it to my localhost directory. It seems the routes are not setup properly but I don't know what I should be changing. In my routes.php file I have:

```
<?php
/**
 * Routes configuration
 *
 * In this file, you set up routes to your controllers and their actions.
 * Routes are very important mechanism that allows you to freely connect
 * different URLs to chosen controllers and their actions (functions).
 *
 * CakePHP(tm) : Rapid Development Framework (http://cakephp.org)
 * Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 *
 * Licensed under The MIT License
 * For full copyright and license information, please see the LICENSE.txt
 * Redistributions of files must retain the above copyright notice.
 *
 * @copyright     Copyright (c) Cake Software Foundation, Inc. (http://cakefoundation.org)
 * @link          http://cakephp.org CakePHP(tm) Project
 * @package       app.Config
 * @since         CakePHP(tm) v 0.2.9
 * @license       http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php MIT License
 */
/**
 * Here, we are connecting '/' (base path) to controller called 'Pages',
 * its action called 'display', and we pass a param to select the view file
 * to use (in this case, /app/View/Pages/home.ctp)...
 */
    Router::connect('/', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'home'));
/**
 * ...and connect the rest of 'Pages' controller's URLs.
 */
    Router::connect('/pages/*', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display'));

/**
 * search controller
 */
    Router::connect('/search', array('controller' => 'search', 'action' => 'index'));

/**
 * offer controller
 */
    Router::connect('/offers', array('controller' => 'offers', 'action' => 'index'));

/**
 * Load all plugin routes. See the CakePlugin documentation on
 * how to customize the loading of plugin routes.
 */
    CakePlugin::routes();

/**
 * Load the CakePHP default routes. Only remove this if you do not want to use
 * the built-in default routes.
 */
    require CAKE . 'Config' . DS . 'routes.php';
```

Please tell me if I need to post more information. My localhost setup is pretty standard, I have each project in a separate folder (e.g. localhost/myproject/ .. on the remote server it's something like www.mydomain.com/projects/myproject/) I used Softaculous App Installer to setup the remote project directory, and I edit it using a online IDE so the files have never been on my localhost server before. Just pulled them down now. Woudl appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Thanks

UPDATE:

$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] is being set here in lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php if it helps...

```
/**
 * Parse URL params into a 'request'
 *
 * @return void
 */
    protected function _parseParams() {
        if (!$this->_paramsParsed) {
            if (!isset($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])) {
                $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = '';
            }
            foreach ($this->params as $key => $value) {
                if (isset($_GET[$key])) {
                    $this->params[$key] = $_GET[$key];
                }
            }
            if (isset($_GET['code_coverage'])) {
                $this->params['codeCoverage'] = true;
                $this->_checkXdebug();
            }
        }
        if (empty($this->params['plugin']) && empty($this->params['core'])) {
            $this->params['app'] = true;
        }
        $this->params['baseUrl'] = $this->_baseUrl;
        $this->params['baseDir'] = $this->_baseDir;
    }
```

Comment: What server locally are you using? You should create virtual host for cake, and what is the problem exactly?

Comment: What happens when you try to navigate to your site on your localhost?  Do you receive an error message and, if so, what is it?

Comment: Please provide OS information and CakePHP version? Also share errors or warning in case you tried something.

Comment: When I navigate to the site, the HTML shows for the index file but the CSS/ JS file links are not working. When I navigate to other pages, it gives me a 404 not found. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, I'm not sure what CakePHP version it is. Where can I find this?

Answer (score 0):

The Routes is not causing any problem. You will need to check where server name or base URL is being set (it might have been set by the old developer):

1. Check for `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']` somewhere in `AppController`, or
2. Check if the ex-developer has stored the `base-url` in the database

Comment: I've found a single instance of '$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = ' in lib/Cake/TestSuite/CakeTestSuiteDispatcher.php .. I've updated my post. I don't know if, or what to, I should change it.